# Stop input after watchdog refresh

Tags: python, input

I have a problem with python input.

Im creating a python sneakers bot, I have a cli setup that when opens it shows you the amount of .txt files that are in the directory and then an input asking you to choose which ones you wanna use to start your task. [1]
i implemented watchdogs that look into my directory to see if file are added or modified, when files get modified watchdogs script refreshes the cli but the input the user was asked still active. I need to stop the input [1] after the screen get cleaned, how can I make this possible?

here is my code:

```
def proxieschoice():

import findfiles
findfiles.my_observer.start()
proxiesfile = 0
proxynamelist = {}

print('------------------------------')
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    proxiesfile = proxiesfile +1
    with open(file) as f:
        count = sum(1 for _ in f)
        proxynamelist[proxiesfile] = file
        print(f"[{Fore.BLUE}{proxiesfile}{Style.RESET_ALL}] {file} [{count} proxies]")
print('------------------------------')



try:
    
    prox = int(input(f"{Fore.BLUE}>> {Style.RESET_ALL} Which proxies you want to use? "))

except ValueError:
     print('Invalid Input')
     proxieschoice()
```

here is findfiles.py

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler
import converse


patterns = ["*"]
ignore_patterns = None
ignore_directories = False
case_sensitive = True
my_event_handler = PatternMatchingEventHandler(patterns, ignore_patterns, ignore_directories, case_sensitive)


def on_created(event):
    converse.cleanscreen()
    converse.proxieschoice()

def on_deleted(event):
    converse.cleanscreen()
    converse.proxieschoice()

def on_modified(event):
    converse.cleanscreen()
    converse.proxieschoice()

def on_moved(event):
    converse.cleanscreen()
    converse.proxieschoice()


my_event_handler.on_created = on_created
my_event_handler.on_deleted = on_deleted
my_event_handler.on_modified = on_modified
my_event_handler.on_moved = on_moved


path = "."
go_recursively = True
my_observer = Observer()
my_observer.schedule(my_event_handler, path, recursive=go_recursively)
```

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: @Ram i updated my questions with code.